# window.onerror not working when CSP error

Tags: javascript

I have used the following code to catch the csp error but it is not working:

```js
    window.onerror = function(msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error) {
      var string = msg.toLowerCase();
      var substring = "script error";
      if (string.indexOf(substring) > -1) {
        alert('Script Error: See Browser Console for Detail');
      } else {
        var message = [
          'Message: ' + msg,
          'URL: ' + url,
          'Line: ' + lineNo,
          'Column: ' + columnNo,
          'Error object: ' + JSON.stringify(error)
        ].join(' - ');

        alert(message);
      }

      return false;
    };
```

with `onsecuritypolicyviolation` , I can get the information for the error but can I get this error info with onerror?